# Maintain NA's after aggregation R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate, na

I have a data frame as follows

```
test_df<-data.frame(col1=c(1,NA,NA,4,5),col2=c(3,NA,NA,5,6),col3=c("a","b","c","d","c"))
test_df
 col1 col2 col3
   1    3    a
   NA   NA   b
   NA   NA   c
   4    5    d
   5    6    c
```

I am aggregating data based on col3

```
agg_test<-aggregate(list(test_df$col1,test_df$col2),by=list(test_df$col3),sum,na.rm=T)
agg_test
Col3 col1 col2
 a    1    3
 b    0    0
 c    5    6
 d    4    5
```

From what I know for summation to be correct we need to explicitly define what is to be done with NA's, in this case I have specified that NA's are to be removed from summation, I guess internally R converts all NA's to 0 and sums up according to the by condition. I need to treat the NA's and 0's in my data differently and therefore have to maintain the NA's that are valid (in this case the observations for b are NA's and not 0). How can I achieve this?

```
Expected o/p
Col3 col1 col2
a    1    3
b    NA   NA
c    5    6
d    4    5
```

Comment: What output are you looking for? Right now you are using `na.rm=T` to ignore NAs. Is the same with `na.rm=F` what you want?

Comment: I want the values for **b** to be `NA` and not `0`, `na.rm =F` will not aggregate observations for **c**, I want to handle both conditions if there are multiple observations and they have `NA` the output should be numerical sum and if the observation is only `NA` then the `NA` should be maintained.

Comment: Show the output you expect in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like (based on your comments to requests for clarification) you want aggregate your groups so you get `NA` if all the values are missing, and otherwise you want the sum of the non-missing values. You can pass `aggregate` a user-defined function that has this behavior:

```
aggregate(list(test_df$col1,test_df$col2), by=list(test_df$col3),
          function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm=T)))
#   Group.1 c.1..NA..NA..4..5. c.3..NA..NA..5..6.
# 1       a                  1                  3
# 2       b                 NA                 NA
# 3       c                  5                  6
# 4       d                  4                  5
```

Comment: Thanks josilber .. great way to do it :)

Comment: how can i replicate this to the data.table syntax of `test_df[,list(sum(col1),sum(col2)),by=col3]`

Comment: @ghub24 I could nearly replicate it with `test_dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NaN, sum(x, na.rm=T))), by=col3, .SDcols=c("col1", "col2")]`, but it was giving me errors if I used `NA` instead of `NaN`. I'm not terribly familiar with the `data.table` package, and if you're having issues getting it to work properly with that package I'd suggest posting a separate question about that.

Answer (score 4):

```
 library(data.table)
 unique(setDT(test_df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
                replace(x, !all(is.na(x)), sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))) , by=col3])

 #   col3 col1 col2
 #1:    a    1    3
 #2:    b   NA   NA
 #3:    c    5    6
 #4:    d    4    5

 test_df1 <- test_df
 test_df1$col2[2] <- 2
 unique(setDT(test_df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x)
                replace(x, !all(is.na(x)), sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))) , by=col3])
 #  col3 col1 col2
 #1:    a    1    3
 #2:    b   NA    2
 #3:    c    5    6
 #4:    d    4    5
```

#### Update

Or using the compact code suggested by @Arun

```
 test_df1$col2[5] <- NA
 setDT(test_df1)[, lapply(.SD, 
             function(x) sum(x,na.rm= !all(is.na(x)))), by=col3] 
 #   col3 col1 col2
 #1:    a    1    3
 #2:    b   NA    2
 #3:    c    5   NA
 #4:    d    4    5
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the much better and elegant conditional code.

Comment: @Arun I guess there is a bug in the code.  I am updating the code

Comment: I see. Then it can be simplified to `!all(is.na(x))`.